# How do you create radio buttons through pure JavaScript by using an object to assign an element from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, radio-button, element

I was on discord and someone need help with this as they wanted to solve this problem.
They precisely said **"I want to check if the selected button has the same value as the true element ( i m working with vanilla JavaScript)"**

This is what they did as an example;

```
var ask =  {
        name: jane,
        age: [18, 20, 24],
        true: 1 // the age of jane is 20
    }
    var option1 = document.createElement("input")
    option1.name = "name"
    option1.type = "radio"
    option2.value = ask.age[0]
    var option2 = document.createElement("input")
    option2.name = "name"
    option2.type = "radio"

    option2.value = ask.age[1]
    var option3 = document.createElement("input")
    option3.name = "name"
    option3.type = "radio"
    option3.value = ask.age[2]
```

Comment: Your code looks fine except you never added the buttons to the DOM.

Comment: You need `someElement.appendChild(option1);`

Comment: Please let me know if you would like me to rephrase :D

Comment: What's the question you're asking? Your code creates the radio buttons just fine, it just doesn't display them anywhere on the web page.

Comment: Is there a way to make them visible?

Comment: Like I just said, you need to append them to some element in the DOM.

Comment: Okay, will do that.